# Ordering entity dependencies

Tags: php, algorithm

I have some entities related to each other.

```
Answer
  - AnswerGroup
AnswerGroup
Condition
  - Question
Notion
Question
  - AnswerGroup
  - Theme
  - Notion
Theme
```

Php representation:

```
$entities = [
    ['name' => 'Answer', 'relations' => ['AnswerGroup']],
    ['name' => 'AnswerGroup', 'relations' => []],
    ['name' => 'Condition', 'relations' => ['Question']],
    ['name' => 'Notion', 'relations' => []],
    ['name' => 'Question', 'relations' => ['Theme', 'AnswerGroup', 'Notion']],
    ['name' => 'Theme', 'relations' => []],
];
```

I need to order them so the dependencies come first. Here is the result I'm expecting:

```
array:6 [
  0 => "AnswerGroup"
  1 => "Answer"
  2 => "Notion"
  3 => "Theme"
  4 => "Question"
  5 => "Condition"
]
```

I naively though I could simply use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like that

```
usort($entities, function ($entityA, $entityB) {
    if (in_array($entityB, $entityA['relations'])) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (in_array($entityA, $entityB['relations'])) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

But:

```
dump(array_column($entities ,'name'));
```

Gives

```
array:6 [
  0 => "Answer"
  1 => "AnswerGroup"
  2 => "Condition"
  3 => "Notion"
  4 => "Question"
  5 => "Theme"
]
```

**How can I order my entities ?**

Comment: Maybe you can get inspiration from here: https://github.com/marcj/topsort.php

Comment: I don't understand your sorting algorithm. Answer is not a dependency, but it comes 2nd. And why do Notion and Theme come before Question?

Comment: It comes 2nd because it has only `AnswerGroup` as dependency, so it does not need to go further down (it depends on the original order)

Comment: Is there a reason `Notion` comes before `Theme`?

Comment: @RolandStarke is right.  This problem should be solved with a topological sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing what you want. It uses a recursive function to list all the dependencies (relations) of each entity. The list of relations of each entity is sorted before processing to get the results alphabetically for relations at each level. Finally `array_unique` is used to strip out duplicate entries (e.g. `AnswerGroup` is a relation of both `Answer` and `Question`).

```
function list_dependents($entity, $entities) {
    $sorted = array();
    sort($entity['relations']);
    foreach ($entity['relations'] as $r) {
        $sorted = array_merge($sorted, list_dependents($entities[array_search($r, array_column($entities, 'name'))], $entities));
    }
    $sorted = array_merge($sorted, array($entity['name']));
    return $sorted;
}
$sorted = array();
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $sorted = array_merge($sorted, list_dependents($entity, $entities));
}
$sorted = array_values(array_unique($sorted));
print_r($sorted);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => AnswerGroup
    [1] => Answer
    [2] => Notion
    [3] => Theme
    [4] => Question
    [5] => Condition 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Nsq1t)

Comment: This works for me. (I've just ported it for my Doctrine entities)